# React-Router BrowserRouter paths one or more directories away from root do not work e.g. /bio/new

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

When setting up React-Router BrowserRouter paths, paths one or more directories away from root do not work. e.g.

```
<Route exact path="/portfolio/new" component={Portfolio} />
<Route exact path="/portfolio" component={Portfolio} />
```

> '/portfolio' works but not '/portfolio/new'
>
> '/bio' works but not '/bio/new'

Anyone seen this before?

All my routes work except when I add a second subdirectory like '/portfolio/new'.

It looks looks like it's going to the 404 page I have setup in my Express Routes. Yet when I use '/anythinghere' it routes properly using the react Browser Router * route.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';

import store from './client/store';
import { history } from './client/history.js';

import { Home, About, Bio, Resume, Portfolio, Nav, Footer, Master } from './client/components';


ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router path="/" history={history}>
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
                <Route exact path="/bio" component={Bio} />
                <Route exact path="/resume" component={Resume} />
                <Route exact path="/portfolio/new" component={Bio} />
                <Route exact path="/portfolio" component={Portfolio} />
                <Route exact path="/modal" component={Master} />
                <Route exact path="/master" component={Master} />
                <Route component={Home} />
                <Route path='*' component={Home} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </Router>
</Provider>,
document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: I have checked both my Express Routes setups and ReactRouter BrowserRouter setups and they seem to be ok. I have also done this before in different projects with similar setups and they work fine.

Comment: Figured this out. It wasn't hitting the bundle.js because I had a relative path in the script tag. Had nothing to do with the route configs.

Changed <script src="bundle.js" defer></script> to <script src="/bundle.js" defer></script>

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't an issue with Express or React Router Browser Router. It was an issue with paths.

It wasn't hitting the bundle.js because I had a relative path in the script tag.

e.g. Changed  to